# How to check for collision between the mouse and a rect object

Tags: python, pygame, menu

im creating code for a covid simulator but am a little stuck on the menu.

So far my code for the menu is as followed:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

font_title = pygame.font.SysFont("arial", 35)
font_para = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 15)

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255,255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

menu = pygame.display.set_mode((999, 800))
pygame.display.set_caption('WELCOME TO COVID-19 SIMULATOR')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def Label(screen, text, size, font, color, x, y):
    label = font.render(text, size, color)
    screen.blit(label, (x, y))

Flag = True
def Menu():
    while Flag == True:
        title = Label(menu, "COVID-19 SIMULATOR: Main Menu", 1, font_title, WHITE, 275, 150)

        own_sim = pygame.Rect(350, 290, 290, 40)
        saved_sim = pygame.Rect(350, 390, 290, 40)
        referrences = pygame.Rect(350, 490, 290, 40)

        x_mouse, y_mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if own_sim.collidepoint((x_mouse, y_mouse)):
            if click:
                own_sim()
        if saved_sim.colllidepoint((x_mouse, y_mouse)):
            if click:
                saved_sim()
        if referrences.collidepoint((x_mouse, y_mouse)):
            if click:
                referrences()
        
        pygame.draw.rect(menu, RED, own_sim)
        pygame.draw.rect(menu, RED, saved_sim)
        pygame.draw.rect(menu, RED, referrences)

        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)

Menu()
```

I need my red boxes to have have text on, which i cant manage to do, and when they are clicked i want them to call another subprogram. I would be very grateful for any help, thanks in advance.

Comment: The title of your question is wrong, because the collison detection works fine.

Comment: Hi, whenever i run it in pycharm it doesnt work, it keeps telling me rect has no attribute collide point

Comment: It's a typo. 1 time you've written `colllidepoint` rather than `collidepoint`

Comment: Oppss, Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your code. `collidepoint` is written with `ll`, not with `lll`:

<s>`if saved_sim.colllidepoint((x_mouse, y_mouse)):`</s>

```py
if saved_sim.collidepoint((x_mouse, y_mouse)):
```